# Is there an R function that turns a frequency table into a prop table?

Tags: r

What is the simplest way of turning a frequency data table into a prop table in R?

This is the data:

```
         Time Total Blog News Social.Network Microblog Other Forums Pictures Video
1  15.KW 2022  1816   23  326             39       678    99     27      523     0
2  16.KW 2022  2535   32  690             42       815   135     26      644     1
3  17.KW 2022  2181   20  362             79       805   110     14      634     1
4  18.KW 2022  2583   19  895             25       692   127      6      658     0
5  19.KW 2022  2337   21  555             22       908   148      8      599     0
6  20.KW 2022  2091   23  392             18       851   119      5      554     0
7  21.KW 2022  1658   17  344             16       650   129      1      417     0
8  22.KW 2022  2476   24  798             24       937   150      7      443     0
9  23.KW 2022  1687   14  341             17       691   102      9      400     0
10 24.KW 2022  2476   21  521             29       984   110     19      509     0
11 25.KW 2022  2412   22  696             31       845   115     29      561     0
12 26.KW 2022  2197   22  715             13       709   128     59      445     0
13 27.KW 2022  2111   20  429             10       937    86     28      474     1
14 28.KW 2022   752    5  121              4       373    42      3      172     0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data frame `df` has a 2nd column called *Total*. It seems that you want to divide subsequent columns by this one.

```
df[-1] <- df[-1] / df$Total
```

After this, the 1st column *Time* does not change. 2nd column *Total* becomes 1. Other columns become proportions.

Comment: This is a good method. One could opt to *keep* `Total` by extending this one, `df[-(1:2)] <- df[-(1:2)] / df$Total`, in the case where knowing the proportion and total "n" are both important (over to the OP/reader if that is important/relevant).

Comment: Wow, you guys! I did not expect the solution to be this straight forward. Worked perfectly, huge thanks! Now, how do I properly round the results to the tenth?

Comment: @xnhZZZ Altogether (with what @r2evans recommends), we can use `df[-(1:2)] <- round(df[-(1:2)] / df$Total, 1)`.